# Сделать регулярное выражение для фрагмента кода

Tags: javascript, python, регулярные-выражения, re

Не понимаю, как сделать регулярное выражение для строки в script

В html файле два значения isMonetized, первый скрипт:

```
<script nonce="VI02iPIKC-XX7AnGIE5ITg">
     const chunkedPrefetchKeys = [];chunkedPrefetchKeys.push({"prefetch_type": "CreatorChannelData", "resolver_id": "id-0", "entity_id": "UC8tmcuV2H191ve_ff6onWrw", "mask": {"channelId":true,"title":true,"thumbnailDetails":{"all":true},"isPartner":true,"features":{"all":true},"settings":{"copyright":{"copyrightAgreementStatus":true},"studio":{"all":true},"coreSettings":{"country":true}},"metric":{"all":true},"permissions":{"overallPermissions":true},"timeCreatedSeconds":true,"isMonetized":true,"isOfficialArtistChannel":true,"isNameVerified":true,"sponsorships":{"all":true},"selfCertification":{"all":true},"channelVisibility":true,"interstitials":{"all":true},"monetizationStatusData":{"all":true}}});window.chunkedPrefetchResolvers = []; const chunkedPrefetchData = [];
      for (const chunkedPrefetchKey of chunkedPrefetchKeys) {
        const resolver = {};
        const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolver.resolve = resolve;
            resolver.reject = reject;
          });
        chunkedPrefetchData.push({
            'key': chunkedPrefetchKey,
            'data': promise
          });
        window.chunkedPrefetchResolvers[chunkedPrefetchKey['resolver_id']] = resolver;
      }
      ytcfg.set({
        'CHUNKED_PREFETCH_DATA': chunkedPrefetchData
      });
  </script>
```

Второй скрипт:

```
 <script nonce="VI02iPIKC-XX7AnGIE5ITg">
     window.chunkedPrefetchResolvers['id-0'].resolve({"channelId":"UC8tmcuV2H191ve_ff6onWrw","title":"saad saad","thumbnailDetails":{"thumbnails":[{"url":"https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLQOdUKfoW6UFWuqAsj8MOXrTthI4y_OUi63thHFMOpNKkQaxlnVomH8SVJaSQcy=s48-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj","width":48,"height":48},{"url":"https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLQOdUKfoW6UFWuqAsj8MOXrTthI4y_OUi63thHFMOpNKkQaxlnVomH8SVJaSQcy=s88-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj","width":88,"height":88},{"url":"https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLQOdUKfoW6UFWuqAsj8MOXrTthI4y_OUi63thHFMOpNKkQaxlnVomH8SVJaSQcy=s176-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj","width":176,"height":176}]},"features":{"unlistedVideo":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_ENABLED"},"customThumbnails":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"channelCreativeCommonsLicense":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_ENABLED"},"legacyNoOffwebSyndication":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"audioOnlyUsage":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"merchandising":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"usagePolicy":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"liveChat":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"posts":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"sponsorships":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"sponsorshipsWhitelisted":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"sponsorsOnlyVideos":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"sponsorsOnlyLiveChat":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"copycat":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"merchandisingActive":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"donations":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"liveStreaming":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED","requirements":{"mustTrustTiersVerify":true,"mustSignLiveTermsOfService":false}},"famebit":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"reels":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"mentions":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_ENABLED"},"liveToAnyMatching":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"liveToLiveOnlyMatching":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"externalLinksInVideoAnnotations":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"unlimitedVideoLengthFeature":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"contentIdMatching":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"selfCertification":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"externalLinksInVideoAnnotationsTermsAccepted":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"restrictScheduledVisibilityTimes":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_ENABLED"},"externalLinksInVideoAnnotationsPrivilegedAccess":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"channelRedirectUrl":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"productListingAds":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"conditionalRedirects":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"channelHiding":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"limitedAdsReport":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"adSpecifyAgeGates":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"trustedToApplyForMonetization":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"canHideViewCount":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"enableCustomizePremiereFlow":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"liveRedirect":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"liveTrailer":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"bmEnabled":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"shortsFundBonus":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"sponsorshipsAnalytics":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"enforceTwoStepVerification":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"productsAnalytics":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"sponsorshipsCommentsFilter":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"prechecksNotifications":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"productTagging":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"superThanksCommentsFilter":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"externalLinksInVideoDescription":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"mobileLiveStreaming":{"status":" CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"supers":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"shoppingAnalytics":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"remixOptOutTos":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_ENABLED"},"remixOptOutTorso":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"pangea":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"},"firstAndThirdPartyTagging":{"status":"CREATOR_FEATURE_STATUS_DISABLED"}},"settings":{"studio":{"currency":"USD"},"coreSettings":{"disableInterestBasedAds":false,"enableVideoAdControl":false,"featureCountry":"DZ"}},"responseStatus":{"statusCode":"CREATOR_ENTITY_STATUS_OK"},"metric":{"subscriberCount":"1222","videoCount":"0","totalVideoViewCount":"0"},"permissions":{"overallPermissions":["CREATOR_CHANNEL_PERMISSION_READ","CREATOR_CHANNEL_PERMISSION_BASIC_METADATA_READ","CREATOR_CHANNEL_PERMISSION_VIDEO_READ","CREATOR_CHANNEL_PERMISSION_VIDEO_BASIC_METADATA_READ","CREATOR_CHANNEL_PERMISSION_MONETIZATION_SETTINGS_READ","CREATOR_CHANNEL_PERMISSION_CAPTION_READ","CREATOR_CHANNEL_PERMISSION_SETTINGS_MANAGE","CREATOR_CHANNEL_PERMISSION_USER_MANAGE","CREATOR_CHANNEL_PERMISSION_WRITE","CREATOR_CHANNEL_PERMISSION_CAPTION_WRITE","CREATOR_CHANNEL_PERMISSION_CONTRACT_SIGN","CREATOR_CHANNEL_PERMISSION_COMMENT_MANAGER","CREATOR_CHANNEL_PERMISSION_CHANNEL_OWNER"]},"timeCreatedSeconds":"1638816207","isMonetized":false,"isOfficialArtistChannel":false,"isNameVerified":false,"channelVisibility":"CREATOR_CHANNEL_VISIBILITY_PUBLIC","interstitials":{"yppWarmWelcomeState":"CREATOR_WARM_WELCOME_STATE_UNKNOWN"},"monetizationStatusData":{"isMonetizationBasicsReady":false,"isLongformAdsEnabled":false}});
  </script>
```

Мне надо достать это значение из второго скрипта, я сделал такое регулярное выражение

```
ismonetized = re.findall("""['"]isMonetized['"]\s*:\s*['"]\s*^(?:tru|fals)e$\s*['"]""",zalupa, flags=re.I)
```

Но оно не находит значение isMonetized, как быть? Причем мне надо найти значение со второго скрипта

Comment: Эвона как Вас на эмоции пробило ))) Может всетаки поменяете имя у переменной )))

Comment: спасибо за совет, поменял

Answer (score -1):

```py
import re
re.search(r'<script.*?chunkedPrefetchResolvers.*?(?<=isMonetized":)(true|false).*?</script>', txt, flags=re.S | re.M).group(1)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, пожалуйста, не заставляйте пересказывать документацию и учебники. Если у ТС возникнут дополнительные вопросы я на них отвечу

Comment: во-первых, пересказывать документацию точно не надо, во-вторых, ни о каком принуждении речи быть не может. // сам вопрос, конечно, мало полезен, а хорошим развёрнутым ответом его можно было бы и «подтянуть». но если не хотите — то и ладно.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin. Неа, не хочу. Ибо, как Вы абсолютно верно заметили, вопрос того не стоит

Comment: спасибо вам, тут гении сидят